# What line is causing this Protractor error?

Tags: error-handling, webdriver, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

Is there a way for Protractor to show in the console log what line the error occurred on? I just get this type of message:

```
Message:
    Failed: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
```

It's hard to figure out if I have so many click commands. I'm running Protractor 1.8.0.

Here is my `protractor.conf.js` :

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  seleniumAddress: 'http://11.111.1.11:4444/wd/hub',

  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--test-type']
    }
  }],

  specs: ['./tests/my_test/*_spec.js'],

  onPrepare: function(){

      global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

      browser.manage().window().maximize();

      var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        filePrefix: 'tests_xmloutput',
        savePath: './test_results_report'
      }));
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

The complete error message would be:

```
Failures:
1) test name description
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 3.206 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

The content of the spec file/test would be:

```
HeaderNavigationPartialPage.myAppButton.click();
LeftNavigationPartialPage.myAppToolsLink.ERROR-ON-PURPOSE.click();  
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(LeftNavigationPartialPage.myAppSearchLink), 10000);
LeftNavigationPartialPage.myAppSearchLink.click();
```

Comment: Well, I usually see on what line this kind of error happens. Do you have any `click()` calls in `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()`?

Comment: nope. I renamed a element variable on purpose just to create this error.

Comment: Could you show the complete output you get and share the protractor config you are using? Also, what protractor version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe yes I will get that info. give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Also, could you show the content of `test name description` spec?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the problem and will let you know anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Reproduced it with `jasmine2` - the reason I haven't seen this before is that we are still on `jasmine1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a related issue at [`jasminewd`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd) project that `protractor` uses under-the-hood:

- [Stack traces for Jasmine2 don't include asynchronous events](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/issues/15)

The issue is now fixed, with `jasmine` upgrade to `>=2.3.1`.

What you should do is to **upgrade `protractor` to `>=2.1.0`**.

---

Old answer:

As a workaround, get back to `jasmine 1.x`:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',

    ...
}
```

Comment: As of 2015-05-15,  the issue is closed – upgrading to Protractor 2.3.1 includes the fix.

Comment: @Dr1Ku there is no protractor 2.3.1 yet, Julie meant jasmine 2.3.1. But, anyway, thank your for the point - updated the answer.