# AngularJs Protractor: Jasmine 2.0 protractor config options

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

Back once again with some more protractor inquiries. I am using Jasmine 2.0 so I can take advantage of the "beforeAll()" and "afterAll()" methods. I am noticing in my console log that the output isn't as detailed the previous version. For example, when test are running, in the console it displays the name of the "it" blocks and also gives the file name, path, and the line number where a failure has occurred. So, I'm wondering if there are configs options for Jasmine 2.0 console output to be a bit more detailed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [protractor line where error occurs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000389/protractor-line-where-error-occurs)

Comment: I read in the link the Jasmine 2 doesn't include asynchronous events in the stack trace. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Yup, there is a link to the open issue in the answer to that question.